# How to pass the list starting from nth element

Tags: python, python-2.7

Suppose I have a list `[1,2,3,4,5]`. Now I want to pass the elements of this list, starting from 3rd element to a method.

i.e. i want to invoke:

```
myfunction([3,4,5])
```

How can I do this in python. tried passing `mylist[2]`, but it doesn't quite work this way it seems.

Comment: Try list slice - myfunction(mylist[2:])

Comment: read about `slices`. use `mylist[2:]`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/509295/699864).

```
mylist = range(1,6)
>> [1,2,3,4,5]
myfunction(mylist[2:])
>> [3,4,5]
```

Comment: Thanks. Pretty powerful tool!!